# Image width doesn't change when resizing window in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

[I created a Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vjecdw2t/11/) to illustrate the problem. Just try to vertically resize the preview window in Safari/Chrome vs. Firefox.

I need the images of my slideshow to be in the container `.slideshow-elem`. *Some* of them are tall and could fill up the whole height of the slideshow, some of them are not, that's why I can't give them a fixed 100% height. My goal is to vertically center those images which are not tall enough and let the others fill the entire slideshow vertically. All of this while keeping the aspect ratio and a dynamic width.

I have done this with the `max-height` attribute on the images and on the `.slideshow-elem` container. It works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox.

Any ideas on how to get this done in Firefox? Thanks a lot!

**Edit:** Also I don't necessarily need the height to by dynamic when resizing horizontally. It is okay for the image to be cropped then. Therefore I updated the Fiddle...

**Edit 2:** Okay, so I took out `max-width: 100%;` on `.slideshow-elem` and it turns out that was all I had to do... Now the image scales properly on Firefox, too. But could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

If you change .slideshow-elem img to

```
.slideshow-elem img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

It will scale properly in Firefox, from your question, you were mostly concerned with keeping the height, so I assume not having it set at max-width is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe this doesn't keep the aspect ratio, that is very important to me. I didn't really thought about the width of the images, but I think there will be a `max-width` set on the container. I'll try to update the Fiddle. **Edit:** Also I don't necessarily need the height to by dynamic when resizing horizontally. It is okay for the image to be cropped then.